# Set specific condition to replace text in Word VBA

Tags: vba, string, replace, ms-word, find-replace

I'm trying to create a macro that replaces a piece of text with specific conditions.

For example:

if it's shown in the document "Summary nº 123" then keep the text the way it is,

but if it is shown "Summary 321" without the '**nº**' in the text, I want the macro to add the 'nº' between Summary and 321 (Summary nº 321) while keeping all the "Summary" followed by nº unchanged and not duplicating them (Summary nº nº 123).

I already tried to use wildcards but to no avail. Maybe I didn't use the right combination of wildcards, but I have no idea on how to solve the problem.

Comment: I suggest asking your question in the SuperUser forum in terms of find and replace and wildcards. For this forum, you need to already have some code you are working with.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (supposed that there is only one space between "Summary and the number or № sign.

```
Sub numer()
Set rng = ActiveDocument.Content
With rng.Find
  .Text = "Summary"
  Do
    .Execute
     If .Found Then
       rng.Select
       Selection.Move wdCharacter, 2
       If AscW(Selection) = &H2116 Then
       Else
         Selection.InsertAfter ChrW(&H2116) & " "
       End If
     End If
  Loop While .Found
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: ok, that one almost solved my problem, the only issue now is that you put № with uppercase **N** and actually the symbol after the n is not underlined, the **º**. For example, I want to put **nº** and not **№**. Maybe there's something to do with the "&H2116"? I'm not quite sure.

Comment: I just realized the &H2116 refers to the unicode of the character, but what I want is much more simpler than that, I want to put a string corresponding to **nº**, but I don't how to do it.

Comment: This can be generated with letters `n` and `o` and then `o` font formatting `superscript` but then to identify it a lot complicated. You have to find an `o` with superscript formatting.

Comment: Could you reformulate the code to add the **n** and the **º**, please? Like, just copying how I put the **nº** here in the form of a string. Sorry, I just have a basic knowledge of vba and I don't how to do it on my own.

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming the text string pattern is `Summary`+`[a Space]`+`Digits`
- `Find and Replace` with wildcards

[image]

- VBA code

```vb
Sub InsertNo()
    With Selection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "(Summary) ([0-9]{1,})"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1 n" & ChrW(186) & " \2"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I did exactly as you wrote but I got a message that could be roughly translated as "The text in 'Find' contains an invalid expression for the coincident pattern"

Comment: Which line throws the error? Please try create a new doc and paste text only. Then test the code.